# Style selected option while using box

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm trying to make a custom dropdown option list using the `<select>` tag. I want the selected option to be bigger in font-size than the options in the list.

I added the font-size property to my select menu, but it applies it also to all the options in the list, which makes the list unusable.

HTML

```
<h1>
  All houses located at 
    <select id="allhouses__dropdown">
</h1>
    <option value=""><a>Alle</a></option>
    <option value=".tilburg" selected><a>Tilburg</h1></a></option>
    <option value=".amsterdam"><a>Amsterdam</a></option>
    <option value=".breda"><a>Breda</a></option>
    <option value=".delft"><a>Delft</a></option>
    <option value=".den-haag"><a>Den Haag</a></option>
    <option value=".eindhoven"><a>Eindhoven</a></option>
    <option value=".enschede"><a>Enschede</a></option>
    <option value=".groningen"><a>Groningen</a></option>
    <option value=".leiden"><a>Leiden</a></option>
    <option value=".maastricht"><a>Maastricht</a></option>
    <option value=".nijmegen"><a>Nijmegen</a></option>
    <option value=".utrecht"><a>Utrecht</a></option>
    <option value=".rotterdam"><a>Rotterdam</a></option>
    <option value=".wageningen"><a>Wageningen</a></option>
    <option value=".zwolle"><a>Zwolle</a></option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
#allhouses__dropdown {
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2rem !important;
  color: red;
}
```

Is there a way to apply the font-size styling only to the selected option? The solution include jQuery, but only if necessary.

I made a codepen that shows my problem: http://codepen.io/sanderfish/pen/jWpbrv

Comment: Please post all relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: What's `$primary-color`?

Comment: Added all relevant code. I can't get the solution in the possible duplicate to work. Had tried that already.

Comment: Your `h1` tag is being closed inside your `<select>` tag.

Comment: From the possible duplicate post, i think `#allhouses__dropdown option:checked { // ... font-size style ... //}` does the work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```css
option[selected] {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: blue;
}
```

This will target the select option tag that has the `selected` attribute applied to it. It will not, if you open the dropdown and selected something else, style that option tag. If you're looking for that to happen you'll likely have to resort to JS and adding a CSS class to the selected option tag.

Styling `<option>` tags is fairly limited so don't be surprised if you can't do everything that you'd like to do.

Comment: That may work - but as hungerstar said, the option stylings are VERY limited. I would bet that you cannot do what you want.

Instead, you should be setting up a fully custom select box using HTML and jquery (not exactly what you wanted to hear I'm sure).